# Convert Leaflet WMS layer to Leaflet GeoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms, geojson, getfeatureinfo

Using the Leaflet API I am adding a WMS layer through the L.tilelayer.WMS feature. This feature includes only a certain amount of options such as 'layers','crs','style' etc.

Through the Leaflet documentation I figured that the L.GeoJSON feature includes the 'onEachFeature' option. I would like to use this 'onEachFeature''  option within the WMS layer.

**What would be a solution to apply an 'onEachFeature' option within a Leaflet WMS TileLayer?**

Comment: A tile layer is just a bunch of images, organized to act like a map in your browser, so there are no features to iterate over. Sometimes you can get tiles for the map, and geojson for your features for fast, in-browser interactivity. Or, maybe you could do something with WFS (not WMS) from your server, but that is another question.

Comment: If you're limited to a WMS, then you will need to look at doing a GetFeatureInfo request on the WMS layer to get at any underlying feature information.  This will require that the WMS layers are queryable.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this plugin : https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms

It allows you to get info on a popup for each 'feature' of a wms layer.

Comment: *if the WMS supports `GetFeatureInfo` requests.